# Get javascript version from browser !=IE in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my current logging class I log the browser, browser version and javascript version.
The Javascript version I get through

```
HttpContext.Request.Browser.JScriptVersion
```

This works fine for IE, but not for any other browser.
Is there another way (not javascript based) to detect the installed javascript version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard for transmitting javascript version over HTTP, so unless a browser coincidentally conforms to IE's User-Agent header format, you won't be able to get that info